# Jquery UI Accordion is not working on IE7

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I want to ask, why my accordion on IE7 is not working, I tested it on IE8-10 but it's working good. I tried to test it on IE7 and nothing happen, it's just like I place an ordered list in an HTML Page. I also updated my JQuery but still the same problem.

What should I do? Please help...

Comment: That is the requirement from our team that should be compatible to other browsers in IE.

Comment: version of jquery and jquery ui used?

Comment: The version of JQuery is v1.10.1 and on the JQuery UI is v1.10.3 .

Comment: you could refer to this : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-accordion-not-work-on-ie-7

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#accordion").accordion({ autoHeight: false,
                                        animated : false
});
```